# How to return JSONP from rails 4 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to return JSONP from my Rails 4 controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CategoryController < ApplicationController
      repsond_to :json
      def index 
        @categories = Category.all
        respond_with(@categories , :callback => params[:callback])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This returns

```
{"category":[{"id":1,"name":"category a","description":"some description..."},{"id":2,"name":"category b","description":"some other description..."}]}
```

For some reason I'm not getting the `callback()` wrapping of the response - any ideas what I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

I've accomplished this by building my response and then rendering the callback as text.

```
response = params[:callback] + '('+ @categories.to_json + ')'
render :text => response
```